# How can I stack values in receiving component that is being sent through a service in Angular?

Tags: angular, service, components, interaction

I'm making simple webshop where I'm sending a movie from "product-component" through a "cart-service" to the "cart-component" using BehaviorSubject and observable.

It is working, but I only send one movie and it always replaces the old one with the new object being sent when I press "buy".

I've tried stuff like ++ or += basically everywhere but then it won't compile.

Product-Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { IMovie } from '../interfaces/IMovie';
import { CartService } from '../services/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-movie',
  templateUrl: './display-movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-movie.component.scss']
})

export class DisplayMovieComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() movie: IMovie;

   message: string;

   constructor(private cartservice: CartService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

  addToCart(movie){
    this.cartservice.updateCart(movie);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(movie));
  }

}
```

HTML

```
 <button (click)="addToCart(movie)" class="btn-add">Buy</button>
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { IMovie } from '../interfaces/IMovie';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

  private cartSource = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

  currentShoppingCart = this.cartSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  updateCart(item: any[]){
    this.cartSource.next(item);

  }
}
```

Cart-Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../services/cart.service';
import { IMovie } from '../interfaces/IMovie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  item: IMovie[];

  constructor(private cartservice: CartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.cartservice.currentShoppingCart.subscribe(item => this.item = item)
  }
}
```

I want the cart to stack the items as an array and then display this array in the cart-component view.

Answer (score 1):

Re '++' and '+=' you can use those only with numbers, so they won't be much of a help with arrays or observables.
For adding items to an array you can either use myArray.push(item) which will add item at the end, or myArray.unshift(item) which will add the item to the beginning of the array.

General advice - if your property holds array - like yours 'item: IMovie[]' it's better to name it 'items: IMovie[]'.

One of the possible solutions to your problem could be if CartService would have a property 'cart' - which would be array of movies.
Then the 'addMovie' method would be adding the currently selected movie to that array and broadcasting that new array using the BeaviorSubject's 'next' method.

```
export class CartService {
    private cartSource = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
    private cart: IMovie[] = []

    currentShoppingCart = this.cartSource.asObservable();  

    addMovie(movie: IMovie){
        this.cart.push(movie);
        this.cartSource.next(this.cart);
    }
}


export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    items: IMovie[];

    constructor(private cartservice: CartService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cartservice.currentShoppingCart.subscribe(items => this.items = items)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working! Now I just need to access this array data somehow, I get Object Object when trying to print items.name for example in my HTML. Do I need to loop this in a special way to display it?

Comment: I solved it that aswell! I looped through the items with *ngFor. Would you say overall this is a good solution for a shopping cart?

Comment: How can I prevent same objects stacking after one another? Lets say I buy 2 of the same I want it to show 2x Interstellar, not Interstellar, Interstellar and so on?

Comment: No problem. One possible solution is storing cart items in a dictionary (object where keys will be ids of movies). Have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nthmtz

Comment: That worked, thank you! The only problem with that is that the map function gives the cart-items new ids (my movie id-list starts at 64). This will be an issue when I save every new item to localstorage because the ids wont match. In localstorage the ID will be 64, 65 etc and the ids in the cart will be 0,1,2 etc. How can I solve that?